# Series of moments of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, reference-request

I am interested in the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\operatorname E[|X|^pI_{\{|X|>b_n\}}],
$$
where $X$ is a random variable with $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$ for some $p>0$, $I_A$ is the indicator function of a set $A$ and $\{b_n\}$ is a real sequence. My question is as follows:

> What is the slowest growing sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that the series converges only under the assumption of $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$?

We have that $\operatorname E[|X|^pI_{\{|X|>b_n\}}]\to0$ if $b_n\to\infty$ since $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$. If $b_n=n^{1/p}$ for each $n\ge1$, then the series converges if and only if $\operatorname E[|X|^p\log|X|I_{\{|X|>1\}}]<\infty$ (a slightly stronger condition than $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$). I think that if we chose a sequence $\{b_n\}$ that grows faster than $n^{1/p}$, the series would converge only under the condition of $\operatorname E|X|^p<\infty$. Unfortunately, I am unable to find such a sequence.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In general there will be no such "slowest" sequence; given such a sequence we can always modify $\tilde{b}_n = b_n - e^{-n} < b_n$, but $\tilde{b}_n$ and $b_n$ have the same convergence properties.

Comment: @snarski I agree with you. I'm still not sure how to properly phrase my question. We're only interested in the growth rate of the sequence $b_n$ and the growth rate of $b_n$ and $\tilde b_n$ is the same (i.e. $b_n\sim\tilde b_n$), right?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I will assume that $p=1$ and that $(b_n)_n$ is increasing. Then by the Cauchy condensation criterion, the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\mathbb  E[|X|I_{\{|X|>b_n\}}]$ is equivalent to that of $\sum_i \mathbb E[|X|I_{\{ |X|\gt b_{2^i} \}} ]$.

Althought we know that $\lim_{a\to +\infty}\mathbb E[|X| I_{\{|X|\gt a \}} ]=0$, the decay may be arbitrarily slow (consider $X$ with integer values), hence a condition on the sequence $(b_n)_n$ will necessarily involve $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. $\{b_n\}$ can depend on $X$, that's perfectly fine as long as $\{b_n\}$ is a real sequence.